# Visual Studio code: C++ syntax highlighting for classes

Tags: c++, syntax, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get Visual Studio code (Linux) to highlight custom classes and data types for C++?

I want this so that when I create a function that returns a certain data-type, it will highlight it correctly and help with readability at a glance.

Comment: Why the C tag ?

Comment: structs exist in c and are kind of a custom data-type

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Could this be relevant for you: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers

Comment: ok so im working with sdl at the moment and say for example i have this line: `SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;`

it would be great if SDL_Surface (its a struct) was an actual color because at the moment the entire line is just white (aprat from NULL and '=') this will help when i create functions like this: `SDL_Surface* loadSurface(std::string path){}`

Comment: Any luck ? I am still facing the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we have the solutions!

vscode cpp team have released a [inside builder](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases/tag/0.24.0-insiders) and can do [Syntactic/lexical and semantic colorization](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/colorization.md)

Comment: Just to clarify: As of VSCode 1.37.1, this capability is in the usual [C++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) (cpptools) extension.  But, make sure you are using a theme such as "Light+" that takes advantage of the new capability.  Some themes, such as ordinary "Light", do not.  See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-code-c-c-extension-july-2019-update/) for more information.